# Possible to cancel paging in ListView using DataPager

Tags: asp.net, listview, datapager

I'm using a datapager control on my listview to perform paging in it.

When paging through the table, I need to perform some validations. When these validations are not successfull, the paging should be cancelled.

I currently perform the validation in the PagePropertiesChanging event of the ListView, however, the arguments do not provide a Cancel property.

```
protected void MyListView_PagePropertiesChanging(object sender, PagePropertiesChangingEventArgs e)
{
     if (!Validate())
     { // cancel the paging action}
}
```

Does anyone know if canceling the paging is possible and how to perform it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I too was disappointed to find there was no simpler way to do this.  I ended up very much like Littlefool, where I made use of the `PagePropertiesChanging` event.  In it, if my validation did not pass, I called the `SetPageProperties()` on my DataPager with a saved off value of its previous `StartRowIndex` value, which I save off in the ViewState.

Not my proudest solution but it works.

Comment: yes, this seems like the "only" way. I ended up with implementing the next/previous using the TemplatePagerField. Once they complain about the numeric paging, i'll do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not simply manually page?

Eg Validate then page if OK, as opposed to try and page, validate, then cancel.

Comment: yes, but i was wondering if it was possible with the build-in pager controls. i was able to implement the next/previous using the TemplatePagerField and its PagerCommand, but am not able to replicate the NumericPagerField